# Arraylist values not coming in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` as below:

```
public static HashMap submitService(HashMap inputMap) throws Exception
    {
        //code....

        ArrayList<String> allIdsList = (ArrayList<String>) inputMap.get("Result_List");
        // System.out.println("Result List: " + allIdsList); prints the arraylist (e.g. [2, 21, 6, 3]

        for(int i=0;i<allIdsList.size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println(" values: " + (String)allIdsList.get(i));
            }
    }
```

the `arraylist` is printing in the console(I tried it only to see if the list is not empty). But for `(String)allIdsList.get(i)` inside the for loop following error message is coming

```
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Would really appreciate someone's help.

Comment: why are you casting to string? You initialized the arraylist with `<String>`. Therefore the get method should return a String, without the need to cast! Same goes for the hashmap. Try to init it with `HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> inputMap`

Comment: @snieuw You're right. This is more a conception problem.

Comment: String.valueOf(allIdsList.get(i)) worked for me...:)

Comment: Even if it works, think about waht you are doing (even if only for later reference). your getting one element of a arraylist, filled with strings, and you need to cast it to string to work, because appearently it contains long and not strings...Something is wrong there, probably with the argument in the method call. Just be careful this doesn't bite you in the a... later on :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure HashMap is of type `HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>`

Answer (score 0):

Replace: public static  submitService(HashMap<'String,ArrayList<'String>> inputMap) throws Exception

Looking at the exception, its sure that the parameter passed does not have arraylist of string.Looks like it might be ArrayList<'Object>(with long value present in the list which eventually is casted in String) or Arraylist<'Long>.

Comment: HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>, there is some problem with editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> submitService(HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> inputMap) throws Exception
{
    //code....

    ArrayList<String> allIdsList = inputMap.get("Result_List");
            for(int i=0;i<allIdsList.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(" values: " + allIdsList.get(i));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is this `inputMap` coming from? By the looks of it, its values are not of type `ArrayList<String>` but something like `ArrayList<Object>` or even `ArrayList<Long>`. The problem seems to be somewhere outside your posted snippet.

Since you're working with raw types in this method, the compiler won't complain (although it should warn you about using raw types). However, the VM will throw a `ClassCastException` where the cast fails - that's what you're seeing.

Try strengthening your signature by only accepting `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` as `inputMap`. That way, you can get rid of those awful casts, as you now get *compile time* type checks. In the best case, this will give the compiler enough information to point out where you're calling this method with an incorrectly typed `inputMap`. You should then be able to easily fix the error merely by following the compiler's instructions. If that doesn't work, you're probably using raw types in your calls as well and you'll need to dig down the stack trace to fix those.